# Unable to find out why my HashInsert and HashFind functions are wrong

Tags: c, hashtable, hash-function, linear-probing

The question is about coalesced hashing. It is for a school assignment, I have no one to ask.
I managed to pass the sample case but unable to pass any of the hidden test cases.

I am dying inside now.

Please send help.

I have attached the full code, I am only supposed to work on the `HashInsert()` and `HashFind()` functions.

[image: an exmple of how its supposed to look like]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TABLESIZE 37
#define PRIME     13

enum Marker { EMPTY, USED };

typedef struct _slot {
    int key;
    enum Marker indicator;
    int next;
} HashSlot;

int HashInsert(int key, HashSlot hashTable[]);
int HashFind(int key, HashSlot hashTable[]);

int hash(int key)
{
    return (key % TABLESIZE);
}

int main()
{
    int opt;
    int i;
    int key;
    int index;
    HashSlot hashTable[TABLESIZE];

    for (i = 0; i < TABLESIZE; i++) {
        hashTable[i].next = -1;
        hashTable[i].key = 0;
        hashTable[i].indicator = EMPTY;
    }

    printf("============= Hash Table ============\n");
    printf("|1. Insert a key to the hash table  |\n");
    printf("|2. Search a key in the hash table  |\n");
    printf("|3. Print the hash table            |\n");
    printf("|4. Quit                            |\n");
    printf("=====================================\n");

    printf("Enter selection: ");
    scanf("%d", &opt);
    while (opt >= 1 && opt <= 3) {
        switch (opt) {
        case 1:
            printf("Enter a key to be inserted:\n");
            scanf("%d", &key);
            index = HashInsert(key, hashTable);
            if (index < 0)
                printf("Duplicate key\n");
            else if (index < TABLESIZE)
                printf("Insert %d at index %d\n", key, index);
            else
                printf("Table is full.\n");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Enter a key for searching in the HashTable:\n");
            scanf("%d", &key);
            index = HashFind(key, hashTable);

            if (index != -1)
                printf("%d is found at index %d.\n", key, index);
            else
                printf("%d is not found.\n", key);
            break;

        case 3:
            printf("index:\t key \t next\n");
            for (i = 0; i < TABLESIZE; i++)
                printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n", i, hashTable[i].key, hashTable[i].next);
            break;
        }
        printf("Enter selection: ");
        scanf("%d", &opt);
    }
    return 0;
}

int HashInsert(int key, HashSlot hashTable[])
{
    // Write your code here
    int index = hash(key);

    if (hashTable[index].key == key) {
        return -1;
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < TABLESIZE; x++) {
        int index2 = hash(key + x);
        if (hashTable[index2].key == key) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (hashTable[index2].indicator == EMPTY) {
            hashTable[index2].key = key;
            hashTable[index2].indicator = USED;
            if (x > 0) {
                hashTable[index].next = index2;
            }
            return index2;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int HashFind(int key, HashSlot hashTable[])
{
    // Write your code here
    int index = hash(key);

    for (int x = 0; x < TABLESIZE; x++) {
        if (hashTable[x].key == key) {
            return x;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I do not know what is wrong with the code, I have tried many sample test cases but still did not figure it out.

Comment: You don't use the `index` variable in.`HashFind`.

Comment: Ask your teacher for advice. When I was teaching a similar class, I happily answered such debugging questions about homework. Your teacher has info and insight about this homework a typical StackOverflow user doesn't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is incorrect: you never test the hash slot `indicator` to check for empty slots.

In the `HashFind()` function, you should stop immediately if the slot `indicator` is `EMPTY` and follow the `next` chain and stop when `next` is `-1`.

In the `HashInsert()` function, you must update the `next` and `indicator` fields as you insert the key in an available spot.

Also note that the `hash` function must ensure that the return value is in the range `0` to `TABLESIZE-1`.  The current implementation may return negative values for negative keys.

Here are modified versions:

```
int hash(int key) {
    // return index in range 0 to TABLESIZE-1
    return (unsigned)key % TABLESIZE;
}

int HashFind(int key, HashSlot hashTable[]) {
    int index = hash(key);
    for (;;) {
        if (hashTable[index].indicator == EMPTY)
            return -1;
        if (hashTable[index].key == key)
            return index;
        // follow the next chain
        index = hashTable[index].next;
        if (index < 0)
            return -1;
    }
}

int HashInsert(int key, HashSlot hashTable[]) {
    int index = hash(key);
    for (;;) {
        if (hashTable[index].indicator == EMPTY) {
            // empty slot: insert key here
            hashTable[index].indicator = USED;
            hashTable[index].key = key;
            return index;
        }
        if (hashTable[index].key == key) {
            // key already present
            return -1;
        }
        if (hashTable[index].next >= 0) {
            // follow the next chain
            index = hashTable[index].next;
        } else {
            // otherwise try and allocate a new slot
            int index2 = index;
            for (int x = 1; x < TABLESIZE; x++) {
                index2 = (index2 + PRIME) % TABLESIZE;
                if (hashTable[index2].indicator == EMPTY) {
                    // use the empty slot and link it in the chain
                    hashTable[index2].indicator = USED;
                    hashTable[index2].key = key;
                    hashTable[index].next = index2;
                    return index2;
                }
            }
            return TABLESIZE;   // table is full
        }
    }
}
```